# Does the derivative function integrable if it equals to 0 a.s. in an inclusive range?

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals

We know that $f$ is differentiable in [a,b]

If $f^{'}(x)=0$ $a.e. x\in[a,b]$, can we reach the conclusion that $f^{'}$ is Riemann integrable in [a,b]? In another word, $f^{'} \in R[a,b]$.

(Here if $f$ is just a common function, then `Dirichlet Function` can easily overturn this conclusion. So I think the trick here is how to use the properties of derivative functions.)

Comment: @cmk No. For example the  characteristic function of $\Bbb Q$ equals $0$ almost everywhere but is not continuous anywhere. (It's not a derivative, so this is not a counterexample to the OP...)

Comment: @David C. Ullrich Absolutely, I wasn't thinking. My mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a non-trivial theorem in an older edition of Rudin's RCA which says the following: if $f'$ exists **at very point** of $[a,b]$ and $f'$ is Lebesgue integrable then $f(y)-f(x)=\int_x^{y}f'(t)\, dt$. [I don't see it in my copy of the book and I don't know why this cute result was deleted!].   Granting this theorem it follows that $f$ is actually a  constant. NOTE: differentiability at every point is used in the proof. Even a countable number  of points of non-differentiabilty makes the conclusion invalid.

Comment: In the conclusion you cited, $f^{'}$ is Riemann-integrable or Lebesgue-integrable?

Comment: Lebesgue integrable.

Comment: Right, but it seems this should be easier. (The result you cite is 7.21 in the third edition;  my recollection is it was stated without proof in an earlier edition...)